# Why does Angular have ElementRef wrapper if it only has a nativeElement field?

Tags: angular

Why not just return the `nativeElement` in `ViewChild` or similar places?

Answer (score 0):

`nativeElement` can represent different types of structures, in this case the DOM, but Angular was also thought to be compiled for mobile and others, so `nativeElement` could be an XML or an unknown structure.

So the Angular way of developing is to access native elements through abstractions, however, as it is impossible to foresee all scenarios, Angular implements `nativeElement:any`, and the developer has to know what he is doing.

Therefore it is **NOT recommended**, as the developer can introduce security flaws such as XSS attacks. The structure of the nativeElement may change upon deployment, thus introducing errors. And the framework doesn't do any binding on changes that the developer makes to the nativeElement.